# Unable to login azure bots and get tokens

Tags: c#, azure, azure-bot-service

I am following this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication everything works well. However,when I test it locally, I cant get access token as doc indicated. See captures below:

[image]
[image]

Any guide is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it works on Azure ?

Comment: Yes.I can get token on Azure.But it not works on local emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls have a check that have you configed [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) for your bot emulator. It will cause some network communication issues if you not configed it.

You can config it here : 
[image]

And everything works as excepted :

[image]

For details about bot and ngrok, [this doc](https://azure.github.io/learnAnalytics-AdvancedFeaturesforMicrosoftBotFramework/lab02-testing_bots/docs/1_Ngrok.html) will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the URL generated above, it looks like your ngrok is not configured/configured correctly in the Emulator settings.

- If ngrok is not configured, then the Emulator will generate a signin link which is similar to `oauth://<oauth-connection-name>&&&<conversation-id>`
- If the ngrok is configured correctly in the Emulator settings, then the Emulator will generate a signin link which is similar to `oauthlink://<signinurl>&&&<conversation-id>`. The `oauth://<connection-name>&&&<conversation-id>` is generated as a fallback, when the
  `oauthlink://<signinurl>&&&<conversation-id>` link cannot be generated.
- If ngrok is not configured, there is no way for the Bot Framework token service (external) to send the token over the network to the Emulator.

Please check if you have ngrok correctly configured in the Emulator settings and points to the ngrok executable. Also, check if you are having multiple instances of ngrok running or you are on a free account and hitting your tunneled connection limit.

Hope this helps.